# there is any way to get localStorage data in OnInitializedAsync method of blazor component

Tags: blazor-server-side

i am trying to get localstorage data in OnInitializedAsync for authorization in blazor so i added blazored.localstorage nuget pagckage for that

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
 {

string token = string.Empty;
try
{
    token = await _localStorageService.GetItemAsync<string>("token");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
{
    navigationManager.NavigateTo("/calculator", true);
}

 }
```

but getting JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time. This is because the component is being
statically rendererd. When prerendering is enabled, JavaScript interop calls can only be performed
during the OnAfterRenderAsync lifecycle method.

getting error JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time. This is because the component is being
statically rendererd. When prerendering is enabled, JavaScript interop calls can only be performed
during the OnAfterRenderAsync lifecycle method.

i want to redirect to other page before render current page.